# Check string for substring with dash

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, dash-shell

I want my motd to make a nice overview of my system status.
ATM I'm trying to check if a deamon is running or not and color it accordingly to it's status.

So normally you would enter `deamon_name status` and it outputs something like `Deamon_name running / not running` I got it to the point where I check if the `Not` is contained or not. That worked.

but then I noticed, that when I actually login and trigger the MOTD, I get some wrong information, I then noticed that I need to use `dash` and not bash or shell.
And now my compare funtion does'nt work anymore.

```
if [[ $Server_name =~ .*Not.* ]]
    then 
        printf "NOT RUNNING";
    else 
        printf "RUNNING";
fi
```

This is my compare function and the check (later I want to add colors red/green)

$Server_name `Not running.` or `running`

Answer (score 3):

In `dash` you can do pattern matching with a case statement, which would also work in `bash`:

```
case $Server_name in 
  (*Not*) printf "NOT RUNNING" ;;
  (*)     printf "RUNNING"
esac
```

or

```
case $Server_name in 
  (*Not*) printf "NOT "
esac
printf "RUNNING"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by comparing the whole `Server Running` or `Not Running` string from the init script, since I know those messages and dash does not support extended features, this seems appropriate.

```
if [ "$ServerName" = "Not running." ]                # I know those messages
    then 
        printf '%b' "\033[31;1mNOT RUNNING\033[0m"   # print NOT RUNNING in red
    else 
        printf '%b' "\033[32;1mRUNNING\033[0m"       # print RUNNING in greend
fi

printf "\n"
```